# Selecting rolling months data

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

I have situation in table like this:

```
Month Product Score Visit_ID
1      A      2     113
1      B      3     114
2      A      4     115
3      C      5     116
3      D      6     118
4      E      7     119
```

I want to select 3 rolling months of data and want output like this:

```
Month Product Score Visit_ID
3      A      2     113
3      B      3     114
3      A      4     115
3      C      5     116
3      D      6     118
4      A      4     115
4      C      5     116
4      D      6     118
4      E      7     119
```

I know how to do this for first rolling 3 months,, how to do the same for multiple rolling 3 months.
Here is the existing SAS code, I want to do this by SQL, if it takes less code:

```
%macro Rolling_months(Initial_dataset=,Final_dataset=,mon_no=,rollmon_field=);
PROC SORT DATA=&Initial_dataset.;BY &DATERG;RUN;
DATA &Initial_dataset.1;
SET &Initial_dataset.;
BY &DATERG;
RETAIN CNT1 0;
IF FIRST.&DATERG THEN CNT1+1;
CALL SYMPUT('ROLL',CNT1);
RUN;
%put &roll;
PROC SORT DATA=&Initial_dataset.1 OUT=CAL(KEEP=&DATERG CNT1) NODUPKEY;BY &DATERG CNT1;RUN;
DATA TEMP(KEEP=X R);
st=&mon_no.;
st1=%eval(&mon_no.-1);
DO X=ST TO &roll.;
n=0; r=0;
 do n = 0 to st1;
   R=X-n;
 OUTPUT TEMP;
 end;
END;
RUN;
data roll(rename=(&daterg=rolling_months));
merge temp(in=a rename=(x=CNT1)) cal(in=b);
by CNT1;
if a and b;
run;
PROC SORT DATA=&Initial_dataset.1;BY CNT1;RUN;

proc sql;
create table &Final_dataset. AS
       (select 
          A.*,
          B.*

        FROM &Initial_dataset.1 A RIGHT JOIN ROLL B
            ON A.CNT1=B.R

);
quit;
```

Comment: Having a key in your table is a good idea.

Comment: Are you doing this in MySQL or SAS/Proc Sql, or don't care?  Post how you've done this for the first rolling 3 months please.

Comment: The database is MySQL and I use it in SAS/Proc Sql. For just 3 months data, I am creating another variable and assiging the last months value to it.

Comment: Are you using MySQL syntax or SAS syntax?  Pass through connection (MySQL) or libname connection (SAS syntax)?

Comment: And please edit your code into the question.

Comment: I don't have SQL code for this. But I was hoping if SQL can do this in lesser steps. I am using SAS Syntax, but if you can provide any basic SQL approach. I can translate it to SAS SQL.                  @Michael Goldshteyn: Visit_ID is the key

Comment: If you have SAS code then post the SAS code...

Comment: FWIW, 'rolling' things are often much easier in datastep due to automatic first. variables, retain, and the concept of order that SQL doesn't have.  I don't have time to answer this properly right now but the SAS code there will be helpful either for me later or one of the other SAS users now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select month, product, score, visit_id
from t
union all
select month+1, product, score, visit_id
from t
union all
select month+2, product, score, visit_id
from t;
```

This would include "rolling" data for months 1 and 2, which you can filter out with a `where` clause.

Comment: Its giving unexpected results.. Its adding 1,2 to month,, so for 4 months its giving the data like its 1,2,3,4,5,6 months. As in 4 months there are only 2 rolling 3 months.. So I need to combine first 3 months data into one.. next 3 months data into one.

Comment: @munishbansal . . . How do you know you don't want data from months 1 and 2?  Like I say, if you really want data only from months 3 and 4, you can use a `clause`.

Comment: No. what I mean to say is.. I want data of 1,2,3 months combined into one and it should say data month 3, and then for month 4, it should combine data of 2,3,4 and it should say month 4

Comment: @munishbansal . . . The above code does that.  But it also includes month 1 and 2 and 5 and 6.  If you want to limit it to a set of months, then use `where` clauses.  I don't know what the logic is to choose one set of months over another.

Answer (score 0):

With a small modification on Gordon's solution this is probably what you want. I'm not sure on the performance when you have a lot of data. A simple data step might be faster.

```
proc sql;
 select month, product, score, visit_id
 from 
  (select month as month, product, score, visit_id 
   from t 
   union all
   select month+1 as month, product, score, visit_id 
   from t 
   union all
   select month+2 as month, product, score, visit_id
   from t
  ) s1
 inner join 
  (select min(month+2) as minmonth, max(month) as maxmonth 
   from t) s2
  on s1.month ge s2.minmonth and s1.month le s2.maxmonth
;
quit;
```